# SharePoint 2013 designer workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint designer workflow. The workflows triggers an email when a new item is created. The user who created the item gets an email notification. The workflow works fine for all other user except for a particular user. Email is not getting triggered and the workflow is getting suspended. The user has read and contribute access. The user comes from the everyone group.

Comment: can you verify with E-mail id of the user.

Comment: The user has a valid email id

Answer (score 1):

It's a known permission issue, where the current user that runs the workflow should have at least **contribute** permission on the associated list, task list, and history list.

> If you don't need to provide the current users higher permission, so in this case, you should use the **App Step** to ignores the current user permission and provides the workflow authorization for its Identity as a `Full Control`.

**For more details**, check

- [Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)
- [Install and Configure Workflow Manager for SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: The user already has contribute rights

Comment: this is what you have said in your Q **.The user has read access.**

Comment: The suspended error is like value cannot be null